# Adding to a collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

This is a simplified version of what I need to do, so the below may seem pointless.

I get a row with:

```
$firstProduct = Product::first();
```

I also get all out with:

```
$ data = Product::all();
```

I need the first product to be in position 5 so I:

```
$data = $data->splice(5, 0, $firstProduct);
```

But I get back an empty collection.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It might be easier to just sort the products appropriately with something like `Product::orderBy(...)->get()`. If your sort order (moving item #1 to position #5) is pretty straightforward, this will let you get the collection in one step.

Comment: I can't use sort, like i said in my question its a simplified version of what im trying to do.

Comment: Why have you tagged your question as both Laravel 4 and Laravel 5? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lunch method on existing object:

```
$data->splice(5, 0, [$firstProduct]);
```

(don't rewrite the object itself)

Additionaly, use brackets on added element:

```
[$firstProduct]
```

to prevent casting this element to an array and adding all its fields to collections instead of whole object.